# Finding indices of the path in a maze python

Tags: python, search, path

I have a question I am not able to think any logic for:

I have a maze as follows:

```
maze = [[1,1,1,1,1,1],
        [0,0,0,1,1,1],
        [1,1,0,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,1,1,1],
        [1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I want to find all indices of `0`'s in the order of how the path goes.

The code I have tried:

```
rows, columns = len(maze), len(maze[0])

answer_dict = dict()
count = 1
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        if maze[i][j] == 0:
            answer_dict[count] = {"r": i, "c": j}
            count += 1

print(answer_dict)
# {1: {'r': 1, 'c': 0}, 2: {'r': 1, 'c': 1}, 3: {'r': 1, 'c': 2}, 4: {'r': 2, 'c': 2}, 5: {'r': 3, 'c': 1}, 6: {'r': 3, 'c': 2}, 7: {'r': 4, 'c': 1}, 8: {'r': 5, 'c': 1}, 9: {'r': 5, 'c': 2}, 10: {'r': 5, 'c': 3}, 11: {'r': 5, 'c': 4}, 12: {'r': 5, 'c': 5}}
```

Expected output:

```
{1: {'r': 1, 'c': 0}, 2: {'r': 1, 'c': 1}, 3: {'r': 1, 'c': 2}, 4: {'r': 2, 'c': 2}, 5: {'r': 3, 'c': 2}, 6: {'r': 3, 'c': 1}, 7: {'r': 4, 'c': 1}, 8: {'r': 5, 'c': 1}, 9: {'r': 5, 'c': 2}, 10: {'r': 5, 'c': 3}, 11: {'r': 5, 'c': 4}, 12: {'r': 5, 'c': 5}}
```

The wrong output can be seen at pos 5 and 6.

I think I need to take a more recursive approach here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself:

```
def find_path(maze):
    answer_dict = dict()
    count = 1
    SIZE = len(maze)
    #list to store the solution matrix
    solution = [[0]*SIZE for _ in range(SIZE)]

    def solve(r, c):
        nonlocal count
        # FINDING THE END OF THE MAZE
        if c == SIZE-1 and r == SIZE - 1:
            solution[r][c] = 1
            answer_dict[count] = {"r": r, "c": c}
            return True
        if r >=0 and c >=0 and r < SIZE and c < SIZE and solution[r][c] == 0 and maze[r][c] == 0:
            solution[r][c] = 1
            answer_dict[count] = {"r": r, "c": c}
            count += 1
            # Try going down
            if solve(r+1, c):
                return True
            # Try going right
            if solve(r, c+1):
                return True
            # Try going up
            if solve(r-1, c):
                return True
            # Try going left
            if solve(r, c-1):
                return True
            # Try backtracking
            solution[r][c] = 0
            return False
        return 0

    for i in range(SIZE):
        if not solve(i, 0):
            pass
        solve(i, 0)
    return answer_dict

find_path(maze)
```